# pandas crosstab plotting not showing intervals that has zero count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, histogram

file_path is an excel file with a column 'Year' of year numbers ranging from 1940 to 2018 and another column 'Divide Year 1976' indicating Pre-1976 or 1976-Present.

```
# Load excel file as a pandas data_frame
data = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=5, skiprows=1)
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create an extra column in data_frame with bin from 1930 to 2020 with 10 years interval
data_frame['bin Year'] = pd.cut(data_frame.Year, bins=np.arange(1930, 2030, 10, dtype=int))

# Plot stacked bar plot
color_table = pd.crosstab(index=data_frame['bin Year'], columns=data_frame['Divide Year 1976'])
color_table.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(6.5, 3.5), stacked=True, legend=None, edgecolor='black')

# Add xticks
plt.xticks(locs, ['1930s','1940s','1950s','1960s','1970s','1980s','1990s','2000s','2010s'], fontsize=8, rotation=45)
```

The problem here is that colortable.plot() function automatically ignores the interval that has 0 counts, in my case which is 1940-1950. How can I force the code to display bars that has zero counts in certain intervals?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBQ4l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter `dropna` in crosstab.

```
color_table = pd.crosstab(
    index=data_frame['bin Year'],
    columns=data_frame['Divide Year 1976'],
    dropna=False)
```

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

Comment: You are welcome, you have the option of selecting as accepted answer and upvoting, or not